# Как выделить значения в цикле из одного числа в два числа?

Tags: javascript

Только начал изучать JS и потребовалось для самодельного калькулятора на сайт выделить из одного числа два значения, чтобы после их использовать в расчете. Но не смог найти как это сделать, какой цикл использовать.

Например:
Пользователь ввел в value с name X значение 25.15
Мне нужно из этого значения получить значения A и B.
Цикл должен взять число выделить из него 5 (или сколько осталось) и записать в A, потом взять 8 (или сколько осталось) и записать в B. И так пока число X не закончится.
Получается цикл должен отработать так:

> ```
> 25.15 - 5, A = 5, B = 0
> 20.15 - 8, A = 5, B = 8
> 12.15 - 5, A = 10, B = 8
> 7.15 - 8, A = 10, B = 15.15
> ```

В итоге я должен получить эти 2 значения - A и B, чтобы далее их использовать в расчетах.
Подскажите возможно ли это вообще на js сделать? И если да, то посоветуйте что посмотреть или само решение, чтобы разобраться.

Comment: Не знаю как другие, а я логику вообще не уловил

Comment: может я плохо объяснил, попробую на примере светового дня. В сутках 24 часа. Будем считать, что 10 часов световой день идет и 14 часов темнота. Получается если число 40, то 40-10-14-10-6. Итого темнота 20 и световой день 20. Здесь такая же логика, нужно выделить два числа из одного числа. И записать их в две переменные.

Comment: так .....и.... как из `25.15 - 5`  получились A = 5, B = 0 например?

Comment: мы 5 записали в переменную А, B получается пока 0. Далее остается 20.15. Записываем в переменную B значение 8. Получается A = 5, B = 8. А у нас остается 12.15. И так далее.

Comment: там еще и строки оказывается взаимосвязаны :D

Comment: Что-то пока логика прослеживается уровня "[Васька Косой корову украл](https://4tob.ru/anekdots/1377)"

Comment: Удивительно, что люди, которые тут сидят по 4 года, не могут понять, что после слова "цикл" надо прочитать строки подряд друг с за другом, но находят время отослать анекдоты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, так. Частично протестил

```js
x = 25.15
a = Math.floor(x / 13) * 5 + Math.min(x % 13, 5)
b = Math.floor(x / 13) * 8 + Math.max(x % 13 - 5, 0)

console.log(a, b)
```

Comment: Спасибо, в вашем примере работает, как нужно, попробую разобраться